# What conditions are sufficient to prove a transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is affine?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, affine-geometry

What conditions are sufficient to prove a transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is affine?

I currently have shown that the transformation is bijective, points and lines are preserved and also the following:

If $M$, $N$, $X$, $Y$ are points such that $MN \parallel XY$ and $MN$ is parallel to one of the coordinate axes, then the images $M'$, $N'$, $X'$, $Y'$ also satisfy $M'N' \parallel X'Y'$ and $M'N'$ is parallel to one of the coordinate axes.

Do I still need to show parallel-ness in general is preserved or not?

Comment: I think the question is OK. When we have just proved, with Chubarev, the theorem referred to in my answer below, we did not have any idea about the existence of the fundamental theorem of geometry -- we found it in the literature only after we proved our result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line-preserving bijection of ${\mathbb{R}}^n$ onto itself](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139978/line-preserving-bijection-of-mathbbrn-onto-itself)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler : As explained on page 2737 in the paper cited in my answer below, the proof in the book by Berger you cited at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139978/line-preserving-bijection-of-mathbbrn-onto-itself contains gaps/errors. Also, as noted in my answer, one only needs surjectivity, rather than the bijectivity condition assumed in Berger's book.

Comment: In my first comment here, I wrote "When we have just proved". Of course, I meant "When we had just proved".

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes; I still wonder if everything here, including your interesting answer and comment, might not find a better home at the other question. Cf. also the references at [MR 3471078](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3471078).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler : Thank you for your suggestion. I have posted a corresponding answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139978/line-preserving-bijection-of-mathbbrn-onto-itself .

Answer (score 3):

By the fundamental theorem of geometry, if a transformation of $\mathbb R^d$ with $d\ge2$ is bijective and maps lines onto lines, then it is affine. The main result in [AMS Proc. 1999](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwju_oOqoe3ZAhUD3WMKHee4AwQQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fproc%2F1999-127-09%2FS0002-9939-99-05280-6%2FS0002-9939-99-05280-6.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1rShKC6DHdXvfzrdn6gsjS) implies that, more generally, if a transformation of $\mathbb R^d$ with $d\ge2$ is **surjective** and maps lines **into** lines, then it is affine.

So, you don't need the condition "If $M$, $N$, $X$, $Y$ are points such that $MN \parallel XY$ ..." at all. Also, you can relax the conditions of bijectivity and preservation of lines to the conditions of surjectivity and preservation of collinearity -- and you don't need any other conditions to get the affinity.